# I want to add inline video and sound but html tags are not working

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

I am trying to add a inline sound in a web page but when i add and open the web page it plays automatically..I used `<object>`,`<embed>` everything but `autostart="false"` and `autostart="0"`  is not working in IE,Mozilla and Chrome.I also tried to add inline video but it is also not playing.Please help me.I really need a help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the HTML5 way of doing it. The current major browsers can do fine with that. The big advantage: No need for extra plugins and bogous `<object>` and `<embed>` tags.

Example for embedding audio:

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="sound-ogg.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="sound-mp3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

See [w3schools HTML5 audio](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) on this topic for better examples and explanation.

Video is as easy:

```
<video width="800" height="600" controls="controls">
  <source src="video-ogg.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="video-mpeg.mpg" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="video-webm.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

Again, [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) has a deeper explanation with examples.

To convert audio and video to the required formats, I use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/).

For an multi-browser support (HTML5 and no HTML5) take a look at [video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/setup.md). In my humble opinion, this is the best way of including video content.

Comment: @Nettaimanoj - feel free to accept the answer (set this green hook)

Comment: i used u r script and it worked it is not playing unless we click in it but the problem is that it loads automatically can we stop the loading and only load when the play button is clicked????...

Comment: If you use `video.js` you can use options to let video or audio be played/loaded (not) automatically (https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/options.md). For the HTML5-Tag use the attribute `preload="none"` in the video or the audio tag for no automatic play/loading (http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/html/audio/preload.html).

Comment: Again, feel free to accept my answer. Just click the green hook (appears when you move your mouse below the "vote down" arrow).